# Java пакеты, как их правильно представить и понять, что в них отсутствует иерархия

Tags: java, package

Написав это `import java.awt.*;` я не получу, содержимое этого `import java.awt.event.*;`  Хотя казалось бы должен получить, если учитывать, что существует иерархия пакетов. Вроде всё расфасовано по пакетам, в одном пакете, есть еще вложенные пакеты. Но получив доступ к пакету в котором, есть вложенные, я не получаю содержимого вложенных пакетов.  Хочется понять, это получается из-за какого-то особого подхода к структурированию пакетов или же они действительно находятся в иерархической расположенности, но система не дает доступа к вложенным пакетам, если запрошен главный пакет? 
`import java.awt.*;` даст мне содержимое `import java.awt.event;`(заметьте звездочки нет во втором импорте) ? 

Или же `event` это тоже пакет, а `import java.awt.*;` даст мне все классы на этом уровне, но не пакеты?
Выходит как в виндовс: применил, что то к папке, а там вопрос : применить к вложенным папкам? Вроде бы иерархия есть, но влияние на неё контролируется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Java** рассматривает каждый пакет как независимый. Например, локальные пакеты не распространяются на любые «под»пакеты. Я подозреваю, что использование иерархии значимым образом было бы ценным, но дизайн **Java** должен был сделать все максимально простым.

**Java** не рассматривает пакеты как действительно подклассифицирующие друг друга; в то время как `java.util` и `java.util.concurrency` могут выглядеть так, как будто вторая часть является частью первой, однако они рассматриваются как полностью независимые, а точка в основном используется для аккуратности.

Причины этого решения, скорее всего, проистекают из общей тенденции **Java** к простоте. Лучшая практика часто никогда не использовать подстановочные символы импорта вообще.

---

Согласно спецификации [JLS, Section 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), возможны только 4 способа произвести импорт:

> A single-type-import declaration (§7.5.1) imports a single named type,
>   by mentioning its canonical name (§6.7).

**Одиночный импорт по его «каноническому» имени.**

Например: `import java.util.List;`

> A type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2) imports all the
>   accessible types (§6.6) of a named type or named package as needed, by
>   mentioning the canonical name of a type or package.

**Импорт всех доступных типов или пакетов по их «каноническому» имени.**

*Это подразумевает, что будут импортированы все имена дочерних пакетов, но не их содержимое.*

Например: `import java.awt.*;`

> A single-static-import declaration (§7.5.3) imports all accessible
>   static members with a given name from a type, by giving its canonical
>   name.

**Одиночный статический импорт, который импортирует все статические члены пакета.**

Например: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

> A static-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.4) imports all accessible
>   static members of a named type as needed, by mentioning the canonical
>   name of a type.

**Импорт всех статических членов пакета.**

Например: `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

Пакеты позволяют дать одинаковое имя разным классам. Если бы была возможность импортировать с помощью `*` всю суб-иерархию пакетов, была бы неразбериха в ваших локальных именах классов.

---

Ассоциация: [why doesn't Java have “deep” wildcard import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576509/why-doesnt-java-have-deep-wildcard-import), [Java import all from all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457547/java-import-all-from-all)

Comment: Да, конечно была бы неразбериха. Значит , всё именно так как я и представлял. Но почему же не рекомендуется использовать * ? Я так понимаю, потому что наверняка не все классы в этом пакете мне нужны? И этот множественный импорт целесообразен, только в случае импорта большого количества классов из одного пакета, чтобы уменьшить объем кода (в импорте конечно)

Comment: @Turalllb Никакого оверхеда не будет, если вы будете использовать `wildcard`-импорты, однако красивее ваш код от этого станет не всегда, и во многих случаях даже lint-ы кидают предупреждение. Фактически, на результат выполнения кода не повлияет, вручную вы проимпортируете два класса из пакета, или используете `*`.

Comment: Ровно, то же самое применимо и к одиночному импорту статического члена или множественному.  Хотя с другой стороны, пусть даже 9 статических членов из 10 будут использованы, в коде, не стоит делать общего импорта, потому что не будет ясно, использован 10-тый статический член или нет. И каждый выбирает, то что ему кажется разумней.

Answer (score 2):

Нет никакой иерархии пакетов. Есть (псевдо)иерархия названий для удобства. Пакеты сами по себе отдельны, даже если какой-то пакет лежит в подпапке другого пакета, он не является вложенным.

Раздел [Apparent Hierarchies of Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) в первоисточнике:

> At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are not. For
>   example, the Java API includes a java.awt package, a java.awt.color
>   package, a java.awt.font package, and many others that begin with
>   java.awt. However, the java.awt.color package, the java.awt.font
>   package, and other java.awt.xxxx packages are not included in the
>   java.awt package. The prefix java.awt (the Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the
>   relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.

Перевод:

> На первый взгляд кажется, что пакеты иерархичны, но это не так.
>   Например, Java API включает пакеты java.awt, java.awt.color,
>   java.awt.font и много других, которые начинаются с java.awt. Но ни
>   java.awt.color, ни java.awt.font, ни любой другой пакет java.awt.xxx
>   не входит в пакет java.awt. Префикс java.awt (Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) используется для ряда пакетов, чтобы показать, что они
>   связаны между собой *(областью применения)*, но не для того, чтобы показать вложенность.

Comment: да, в этой цитате написано важное. Что иерархия есть только для того, чтобы логически связно расположить  пакеты. Чтобы можно было легко, что тот найти. Вот когда я буду вручную лазить по пакетам, то иерархия будет.  А в самом компиляторе это уже искусственно отключено .