# Что делает точка

Tags: java

При импорте пакетов в Java, используется следующий синтаксис:

```
import java.awt; (например) или import java.awt.*;
```

Что в этих инструкция делает точка? Как вообще она называется, оператор разрешения области видимости?

Comment: Если перевести это в русло физического расположения содержимого, то awt находится в папке (пакете) java.

Comment: `java.awt.*` подключить все из папки awt включая подпапки. `java.awt` подключить все из текущий папки кроме подпапок. Хотя память может мне и изменять -.-

Comment: Это понятно, вопрос как эта операция называется и как называется этот оператор)

Comment: Это не операция и не оператор. Называется точка.

Comment: @Maxim Не находится. В яве [нет иерархии пакетов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815026/java-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85)

Comment: @Эникейщик Открыл файл rt.jar, в нем awt находится в папке java

Comment: @Эникейщик хотя, вы хотите сказать что import java.awt; это не операция?

Comment: @Maxim Это иерархия папок и названий, а не пакетов. Почитайте ответы по ссылке.

Comment: ``import`` - операция. А точка - нет.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Операцию "точка" надо изучить в контексте `пакетов` (`package`).
А затем уже разбираться с оператором `import` этих самых пакетов.

Герберт Шилдт, "Java 8. Полное руководство":

> Для хранения `пакетов` в Java используются каталоги файловой системы.
>   Например, файлы с расширением `.class` для любых классов, объявленных в качестве
>   составной части `пакета MyPackage`, должны храниться в каталоге `MyPackage`.
>   Напомним, что в именах файлов и каталогов учитывается регистр символов,
>   а кроме того, они должны точно соответствовать имени пакета.
>   Один и тот же оператор package может присутствовать в нескольких исходных
>   файлах. Этот оператор просто обозначает пакет, которому принадлежат классы,
>   определенные в данном файле. Это никак не мешает классам из других файлов
>   входить в тот же самый пакет. Большинство пакетов, применяемых в реальных
>   программах, распределено по многим файлам.
>   **В Java допускается создавать иерархию пакетов. Для этой цели служит операция-
>   точка.** Объявление многоуровневого пакета имеет следующую общую форму:
>   `package пакет1[.пакет2[.пакет3]]`;
>   Иерархия пакетов должна быть отражена в файловой системе той среды, где
>   разрабатываются программы нa java. Например, в среде Windows пакет, объявленный
>   как `package java.awt.image;`, должен храниться в каталоге `java\awt\image`.

Соответственно теперь можно раскрыть операцию `import`.

Герберт Шилдт, "Java 8. Полное руководство":

> Чтобы отдельные классы или весь пакет можно было сделать доступными, в Java внедрен оператор `import`. После того как класс импортиро­ван, на него можно ссылаться непосредственно, используя только его имя. Оператор `import` служит только для удобства программирования и не является обязательным с формальной точки зрения для создания завершенной программы нa java. Но если в прикладном коде приходится ссылаться на несколько десятков классов, то оператор
>   `import` значительно сокращает объем вводимого исходного кода.
>   В исходном файле программы нa java операторы `import` должны следовать непосредственно за оператором `package` (если таковой имеется) и перед любыми
>   определениями классов. Оператор `import` имеет следующую общую форму: `import пакет1[.пакет2[.пакет3]];`

Ссылка на подобный вопрос (взято из комментариев): [java-пакеты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815026/java-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85)